# Changing the color of terminal text

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, bashrc, colors

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I mean changing the color of text I type, not user@server.
Have seen some other posts about it, but could not get it to work.
Want it permanent.
I already change the user@server part in bashrc.
If I could get an example of cyan text, 051, or a way to do it?
I have no GUI.
Thanks

Comment: is it a tty or a ssh session? seems ssh session, then your terminal color will be applied I guess.

Comment: I connect with putty / ssh

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/198452/how-do-i-change-the-colour-scheme-on-putty

Comment: If you mean colorizing the input, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20803/117037